# Apache & MySQL with Persistent Disks to Multiple Instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I plan on mount persistent disks into folders Apache(/var/www) and Mysql (/var/lib/mysql) to avoid having to replicate information between servers.

Anyone has done tests to know the I/O performance of persistent disk is similar when attaching the same disk to 100 instances as well as only 2 instances? Also has a limit of how many instances can be attach one persistent disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what setup you're planning to use, so it's a little hard to comment specifically.

If you plan to attach the same persistent disk to all servers, note that a disk can only be attached to multiple instances in read-only mode, so you may not be able to use temporary tables, etc. in MySQL without extra configuration.

It's a bit hard to give performance numbers for a hypothetical configuration; I'd expect performance would depend on amount of data stored (e.g. 1TB of data will behave differently than 100MB), instance size (larger instances have more memory for page cache and more CPU for processing I/O), and access pattern.  (Random reads vs. sequential reads)

The best option is to set up a small test system and run an actual loadtest using something like apachebench, jmeter, or httpperf.  Failing that, you can try to construct an artificial load that's similar to your target benchmark.

Note that just running bonnie++ or fio against the disk may not tell you if you're going to run into problems; for example, it could be that a combination of sequential reads from one machine and random reads from another causes problems, or that 500 simultaneous sequential reads from the same block causes a problem, but that your application never does that.  (If you're using Apache+MySQL, it would seem unlikely that your application would do that, but it's hard to know for sure until you test it.)